# Is it possible to run an iOS app store?

Tags: ios, app-store, implementation

I would like to know that is it possible to implement and run a new app store for iOS apps? I know, iOS devices must download apps only from AppStore, but is there any way to run an independence iOS AppStore website or app?

Comment: _Cydia_ is one of the live options, if that is answer to your question; it works flawlessly on jailbroken devices only; but you can have to Enterprise account, and distribute _your_ own apps via an own server.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is NO. period.

> 3.2.2 Unacceptable
>   (i) Creating an interface for displaying third party apps, extensions, or plug-ins similar to the App Store or as a general-interest collection.

[App Store Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

Answer (score 1):

1. Jailbreak app stores: something like [Cydia](https://cydia.saurik.com/). You can do pretty much anything with / on jailbroken devices.
2. You can easily create a website that is a subset of the official AppStore with different filters / rankings / search capabilites etc. In the end you can only support the apps available in the real AppStore since that is the only place to install apps from
3. Create an entire development environment and ecosystem to create apps which can be installed *inside* your new AppStore2.0 app. But good luck doing that complex task and good luck getting it through the apple review process.

Answer (score 1):

Enter to Apple enterprise program - https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/